# Проблема с поиском потомков

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть следующая структура:

```html
<div class="sub-group">
        <input class="name-bool group_names" value="1" readonly="" data-optional="false">
</div>
<div class="sub-group">
        <input class="name-bool group_names" value="2" readonly="" data-optional="false">
</div>
```

Хочу получить значение инпута, пытаюсь реализовать следующим образом:

```
$('.sub-group').each(function(){
 var pos_name=$(this).find('.name-bool group_names').val();
 console.log(pos_name);
});
```

Но по итогу в консоли получаю 2 undefined

Comment: Потому что селектор `.name-bool group_names` ищет тэг `<group_names>` в элементе с классом `name-bool` . Правильная запись `.name-bool.group_names`

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров,спасибо! проблема решена